# Ошибка, при использовании методов, генерируемых lombok

Tags: java, maven, eclipse, lombok

Для сборки проекта я использую Maven.

**`pom.xml`:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.danilkucheruk</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hibernate</name>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <properties>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

У меня есть класс User:

```
package hibernate.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
 public class User {
    
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String departmentId;
}
```

Но при попытке из другого класса вызвать `User.builde.build()` ,я получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method builder() is undefined for the type User

    at hibernate.HibernateRunner.main(HibernateRunner.java:15)
```

Comment: Очень сильно похоже что нужно добавить плагин ломбок в вашу IDE

Comment: И не просто добавить плагин, а также в настройках идеи, где то в недрах build-compilation секций разрешить обработку аннотаций

Comment: @tym32167, автор вопроса пользуется эклипсой :)

Comment: @NowhereMan упс =)

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка компиляции кода, который использует аннотации Lombok. Для того, чтобы компилировать такой код, надо установить плагин в Eclipse и указать путь в настройках.

Выполните следующие шаги для Eclipse:

1. Закройте вашу IDE
2. Загрузите Lombok jar [отсюда](https://projectlombok.org/download)
3. Дважды щелкните jar
4. Выполните шаги, указанные [тут](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)
5. Откройте свою IDE

Если проблема по-прежнему не решена, закройте проект и откройте его снова.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Если остальные ответы и комментарии здесь не решили ваш вопрос, следующий код для вставки в pom.xml, возможно, сможет помочь. Он включает обработку аннотаций для библиотеки lombok. Код нужно вставить в тег *project* отдельно, вне других тегов вроде *dependencies*.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```